# Changing permission from read only in linux?

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, chmod

I am trying to get the automatic brightness bug fixed in Linux Mint 17 based on the new Ubuntu release. In order to do this i had to create a file named

```
    20-intel.conf
```

in location

```
    /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

but this file and every other file in this directory has read only permissions on it. How do I change this permission to at least this file so that I can edit it?

Comment: Use `sudo gedit /path/to/file` to edit as root. Or run file-manager as root ex:`sudo nautilus /path/to/directory`

Answer (score 1):

Those files are owned by root, so they are not editable by your normal user.

Supposing you have the new file in ~/Desktop, you could copy it with:

```
 sudo cp -v ~/Desktop/20-intel.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

However, it is strange that you need to put a file inside /usr/share/ as that's handled by the package manager. It can probably also work at a place like `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and that would be prefered over `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` (`/etc` is designed for system configuration)